# How to select from multiple custom tables using ActiveRecord Query methods

Tags: sql, ruby, active-record-query

Is there a way to select from multiple custom tables using ActiveRecord QueryMethods? I'm trying to replicate this SQL query using Ruby's ActiveRecord Query Methods.

```
select employee.emplid, address.location
from (....) employee, (....) address
where employee.emplid = address.emplid
```

I can successfully get the first query from employee, but when I try to add the address part it all goes wrong. I've tried doing

```
self.select(employee.emplid, address.location).from(...., 'employee').from(...., 'address')
```

But it results in an invalid identifier error. Should I be thinking about this from a different perspective?

Edit: Included code

```
def self.find_info(login)
  self.select('employee.emplid, address.location').from(
    self.select('emplid, effdt, login').from(
      self.select('emplid, login, effdt, lead(emplid, 1) over (order by effdt desc) prev').
      from('ps_employees').
      where('ps_employees.emplid=(?)', login)
    ).where('emplid != prev or prev IS NULL'), 'employee')
end
```

I was hesitant to include the code inside the from block cause I thought it was somewhat extraneous. At this point the code is able to do the
    select employee.emplid
    from (....) employee
but I'm not sure where to proceed to try and get the address.location information. Inside the (....) address block is another piece of code similar to the employee one where it's returning the location and emplid column of the ps_jobs table.

Comment: Can I define a join on the address table before it's been declared though?

Comment: If you mean you are declaring the `self.select...` in the Employee class, I would think it would load all your classes before it let you call the method. You have very little code listed so all I can do is guess. You should list any classes you've defined.

Comment: Other than the ActiveRecord::QueryMethods that are being called (select, from, where, etc) my code doesn't rely on any other classes. I might be wrong about the SQL query, but I interpreted the
from(...) employee, (....) address block to be creating custom tables and labeling them as employee and address. 

So if I tried doing a join before it, then it wouldn't work because the address table wasn't defined yet.

Comment: Ah, I don't know about that use of AR::QueryMethods. Also I don't know what you mean by 'custom tables'. Do you mean like a temporary table?

Comment: Again, you have to have some other code than what little you posted above, right? Post your code or I really can't help you.

Comment: Sorry if I worded this wrong, I'm not exactly sure on the terminology since I'm relatively new to SQL. But inside the from(...) blocks, I'm selecting a bunch of rows from a table called ps_employees and labeling it employee/address. After that, I'm doing an implicit join on the rows I selected via emplid using the where clause. So custom tables is probably the wrong word usage. I'll be editing the code in right now.

Comment: What database is this? They all have different forms on what is allowed and what isn't. MySQL? Postgres?

Comment: Also include a stack trace for the error you are receiving, not just the type of error.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with pry, using a sqlite3 DB:

```
require 'active_record'

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
end

Employee.joins(:address).select('employees.id, addresses.location')
```